# How can I convert images of pdf files to text?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, text, image-processing, convert

I am looking for a way to convert images of a PDF to a real text file.

I have tried using Okular, GSCAN2PDF, GIMP, ImageMagick and XPDF but I am having problems with all of them, maybe because I don't have much experience with them and I'm struggling to understand the instructions I've found. I would appreciate a beginner-level explanation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "images of a PDF"? Have you seen this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/59389/how-can-i-extract-text-from-images

Answer (score 3):

First install poppler-utils which contains Pdfimages. Pdfimages is a tool command line, which allows to extract all images from a PDF file and save them as JPEG files.

Open a terminal, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Install the software:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

The syntax of this tool is:

```
pdfimages -j file.pdf output_directory
```

Where `file.pdf` is the file you want to extract images and `output_directory` is the directory where you want to save the images.

Images are saved in the following format:

```
output_directory/output_directory-nnn.jpg
```

It's funny, but they are named with the same name of the directory where you extracted, a consecutive number and extension.

Second, just install an application for ocr, for example ocrfeeder:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr ocrfeeder tesseract-ocr-eng gocr cuneiform ocropusocrad
```

Once the program opens, select the search engine you want to use. Select the **Edit** menu and select **Preferences** from the dropdown menu.

In the dialog that opens select the **Tools** tab. Here you will see an option that puts favorite engine. In this option, select *Tesseract* and then press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

After completing the settings we can start with the action

To do this we press the <kbd>+</kbd> symbol:

Then select the image file you want to open.

If necessary retouch the image, only you have to access the Tools menu. Once inside the **Tools** menu select the option *unpaper*. The display will find various options and filters to retouch the image.