# Is there any application to convert gif file to txt file in linux?

Tags: convert

Is there any application to convert a gif file to txt file in linux?

Comment: And what would you want to see in that text file? A gif is not text. A gif is an image. If you want to see the text open it with a hex editor and it will show text in base 16.

Comment: Please clarify - do you have an image *of text* that you wish to convert using OCR - or a general image that you want to display as ASCII-art? or something else?

Comment: It's an old thread but might this one help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/59389/how-can-i-extract-text-from-images

Comment: Actually I have a .gif file that contains some text and I want to convert that text to a .txt file

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [gif2txt](https://github.com/hit9/gif2txt) This GitHub project appears to be able to convert even multi-image gifs to ASCII art. Here's an example source image:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hit9/gif2txt/gh-pages/test.gif

and example output:

https://hit9.github.io/gif2txt/out.html

Comment: That is sooo cool!