# Ubuntu 18.04 error install tesseract

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.

I've installed tesseract using `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

When I type:

```
tesseract -v
```

I had an error:

```
tesseract: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4: undefined symbol: pixaDisplayTiledInColumns
```

Below is the output of `apt-cache policy tesseract-ocr`:

```
Installed: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2
Candidate: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2 
Version table: 
   *** 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2 500 
          500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages 
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Below is the output of apt-cache policy tesseract-ocr

tesseract-ocr:
  Installed: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2
  Candidate: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2
  Version table:
 *** 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: i think when you're installing `tesseract-ocr` package not extracting the archive. try to run `sudo ldconfig` and reinstall it again. or to get it, try to install `libtesseract-dev` package

Comment: -1.  No response from OP - reduced usefulness.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri i  already tried sudo ldconfig, but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug of `tesseract` package, which is found in release **4.00~git2481-555f6ffc-1**. 
Do this:

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5
tesseract -v
```

If it did not help, just [build](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling) `tesseract` from source...

**Update 1:**
You can do

```
sudo apt purge tesseract* libtesseract*
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

to remove everything that belongs to `tesseract`  with configurations. However, it may also remove dependant packages, such as `opencv` (depends to `libtesseract4`)

Comment: Could you please reproduce this bug or give a link to bugzilla? I can't reproduce the issue with 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2 on clean 18.04 LTS amd64 VM.

Comment: @N0rbert, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=903606. The user has probably installed from not official source. The solution is also taken from here.

Comment: i have already installed sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5

Comment: @Olimjon can you please suggest how to remove tesseract with all the folder and reinstall again, i have tried http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/t/tesseract-ocr/uninstall/index.html

Comment: @mayurpanchal, I updated my answer, please check this.

Comment: Can you pleaase let me know Any API which i can integration for the getting text from images

Comment: Check this, however `tesseract` is known to be the best: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59389/how-can-i-extract-text-from-images

Comment: This works for me. Cool  Great answer .i don't know why people down voted you.Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 2):

On my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM with all updates Tesseract installs without any issues.
So it is completely operable.
The linked bug by @Olimjon is not related to current problem as it was reported after 18.04 LTS feature freeze.

On my system I have done the following:

> ```
> $ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y
> ```

and got

> ```
> $ tesseract -v
> tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
>  leptonica-1.75.3
>   libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
>
>  Found AVX
>  Found SSE
>
> $ apt-cache policy tesseract-ocr
> tesseract-ocr:
>   Installed: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2
>   Candidate: 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2
>   Version table:
>  *** 4.00~git2288-10f4998a-2 500
>         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```

So, if @mayurpanchal really want to solve Tesseract problem - then please update all packages in your system and install `tesseract-ocr` again and add requested output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4` to the question.
It may be PPA or third-party libraries issue.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. However, it would have been better if OP has responded.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution for ubuntu 18.04**

Please first install the libraries which are required for tesseract-ocr

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5
```

Then simply install tesseract using command

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y
```